# Angular 10 routing not working in cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova, angular-routing, phonegap

I have a problem in the router when I want to wrap to a Cordova app for android. The problem seems to be in router module but I can't figured what is going wrong.

The problem is this
Everything works well in the angular app when I run it in a browser. All the routes are working correctly and I made a deploy which also works correctly. But when I want to build the apk with the compiled code in "dist" folder, it seems like the routing is not working.

This is my principal routes imported in the app module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  component: AppLayoutComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/dashboards/dashboards.module').then(m => m.DashboardsModule),canActivate: [CheckTokenGuard] },
      { path: 'orders', pathMatch: 'full',  loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/orders/orders.module').then(m => m.OrdersModule), canActivate: [CheckTokenGuard] }
  ]
},
{
  path: '',
  component: AuthLayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: 'session', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/modules/session/session.module').then(m => m.SessionModule) }
  ]
},
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: 'session/not-found'
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then, the auth guard looks like this:

```
export class AuthAdminGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (localStorage.getItem('sessiontoken')) {
      if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('sessiontoken')).type === 'ADMIN') {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    localStorage.removeItem('sessiontoken');
    this.router.navigate(['session/signin']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Auth layout component looks like this:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

As I say, this is actually working in localhost and even in my server, but when I generate the apk It automatically redirects to the "session/not-found" path like it doesn't recognize the root "session/signin".

I build the app using `ng build --aot --output-hashing all` and also I change the base href with `<base href="./">` and put the cordova script in the index.html

I tried everything but nothing seems to work. Pleas help

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out Sergio?